# C# jagged array to list of lists

Tags: c#, list, jagged-arrays

given a jagged array:

```
int[][] edges = new int[][] 
            {
                new int[] {0,1},
                new int[] {0,2},
                new int[] {0,3},
                new int[] {1,4},
            };
```

is there a more elegant way to do this:

```
var adjlist = new List<List<int>>();
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                adjlist.Add(new List<int>());
            }
            
            foreach(var arr in edges)
            {
                int src = arr[0];
                int dst = arr[1];

                adjlist[src].Add(dst);
                adjlist[dst].Add(src);
            }
```

something that improves on the time complexity for this would be ideal.

Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing can be done to improve time complexity as it is already as fast as it can get - linear time for the first dimension (`new List<>()`, list indexing and adding items to a list are constant time operations).

Comment: Is this code working as you expect / want?  because its doing a fairly unusual  and suspect operation

Comment: The code works. It was for a leetcode problem 261 and passes the tests there. To convert an edge list to an undirected graph.

Answer (score 7):

My assumption is the code in your example is not working as you intended (I may be wrong). However converting a jagged array to a list of lists should be as simple as the following. I doubt you will get much more efficient than this, though you could benchmark.

The following is O(n), meaning something somewhere needs to iterate over each element. That's to say, the memory can't be *magicked*. On saying that, `ToList` will call the `List` constructor with the *collection* and use the instance member `CopyTo` which in-turn uses `Array.Copy` and as such is ***extremely*** optimized for the data type and platform.

```
var results = edges.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```